# WPF - Canvas optimisation solution

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, blend

I have some trouble with my WPF project. To be better understood, I have a big drawing spaces in ArchiCAD - where I drawed many electrical components (motors, cable, serrated wheel, gears, electrical plates and other). I export that project to Adobe Illustrator (.ai), and import that file with Blend. For example a small gear have that code :

```
<Canvas x:Name="_30_gear_left_No__1" Height="234" Canvas.Left="67" Canvas.Top="243" Width="476">
    <Path Data="M7.208,0.334L6.814,0.466 6.393,1.557 6.312,1.881 5.237,1.253 4.777,1.451 2.15,3.027C1.727,3.495 1.358,4.007 1.049,4.556 0.654,5.323 0.38,6.146 0.236,6.996L0.184,7.649C0.17,8.048 0.238,8.446 0.384,8.817 0.535,9.162 0.773,9.461 1.075,9.686L0.507,10.253 0.507,10.713 1.461,11.243 0.901,12.29 1.033,12.553 2.018,13.144 1.953,13.538 4.581,15.049 4.898,14.702 5.894,15.312 6.288,15.312 6.843,14.276 7.799,14.786 8.193,14.589 8.589,13.111 9.77,13.406 10.099,13.078 10.033,11.633 10.468,11.213 11.478,11.37 11.807,10.91 11.214,10.013 11.28,9.728 12.791,8.874 12.988,8.414 12.069,7.691 12.069,7.56 13.449,6.377 13.514,5.918 12.526,5.362 13.449,4.144 13.317,3.75 12.397,3.225 12.66,2.436 12.463,2.239 8.981,0.269 8.653,0.203 8.127,0.86z" Height="15.495" Canvas.Left="-0.182" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.368" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Canvas.Top="-0.203" Width="13.714"/>
    <Path Data="M7.207,0.334L6.813,0.466 6.392,1.557 6.311,1.881 5.236,1.253 4.776,1.451 2.149,3.027C1.726,3.495 1.357,4.007 1.047,4.556 0.653,5.323 0.379,6.146 0.235,6.996L0.183,7.649C0.17,8.048 0.237,8.446 0.383,8.817 0.534,9.162 0.772,9.461 1.074,9.686L0.506,10.253 0.506,10.713 1.46,11.243 0.9,12.29 1.032,12.552 2.017,13.144 1.952,13.538 4.579,15.049 4.897,14.702 5.893,15.311 6.287,15.311 6.842,14.275 7.798,14.786 8.192,14.589 8.588,13.111 9.769,13.406 10.097,13.078 10.032,11.633 10.467,11.213 11.477,11.37 11.806,10.911 11.213,10.013 11.28,9.728 12.79,8.874 12.988,8.414 12.068,7.691 12.068,7.56 13.448,6.378 13.513,5.918 12.526,5.362 13.448,4.144 13.316,3.751 12.396,3.225 12.659,2.436 12.462,2.239 8.98,0.269 8.652,0.203 8.126,0.86z" Height="15.494" Canvas.Left="277.517" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.368" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Canvas.Top="174.475" Width="13.714"/>
    <Path Data="M7.207,0.333L6.813,0.464 6.392,1.556 6.311,1.88 5.236,1.252 4.776,1.45 2.148,3.026C1.726,3.494 1.357,4.006 1.047,4.555 0.653,5.322 0.379,6.145 0.234,6.995L0.183,7.648C0.169,8.047 0.237,8.444 0.383,8.816 0.534,9.161 0.772,9.46 1.074,9.685L0.506,10.252 0.506,10.712 1.46,11.242 0.9,12.289 1.032,12.551 2.017,13.143 1.952,13.537 4.579,15.048 4.897,14.701 5.893,15.31 6.287,15.31 6.842,14.274 7.798,14.785 8.192,14.588 8.588,13.11 9.769,13.405 10.097,13.077 10.032,11.632 10.467,11.212 11.477,11.369 11.806,10.91 11.213,10.012 11.279,9.727 12.79,8.873 12.987,8.413 12.068,7.69 12.068,7.559 13.448,6.376 13.513,5.917 12.525,5.361 13.448,4.143 13.316,3.75 12.396,3.224 12.659,2.435 12.462,2.238 8.98,0.268 8.652,0.202 8.126,0.859z" Height="15.494" Canvas.Left="462.933" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.368" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Canvas.Top="218.677" Width="13.714"/>
</Canvas>
```

And all my **CANVAS** pieces from project have over 10000 lines of xaml code. That cause a project overload - and the application becomes impossible to control. WindowsForm slowing/glowing on resize and drag.

Recommend please a better method to draw lines for my project. The final product must be able to react on  MouseEnter - to do some actions on specific pieces from my project, like Info about this element and MouseLeftButtonDown - to add this element to a list.

Thx for any helps.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I copied and pasted your XAML and it works perfectly on my machine. If you have performance problems, those are surely NOT caused by the above XAML. Please be more specific and post the relevant parts of XAML and code.

Comment: I posted a small piece from my project, all of the pieces in project form over 10000 lines of code! And that is my problem, how to work with sow big project.

Comment: So you have 10000 lines of XAML? and it's all visualized on screen at the same time?  I don't  understand

Comment: Yes, I make for you a screen http://s18.postimg.org/ii2zg40q1/5edff6622d6a226a7674a3719079aea872009909.png

Comment: I seriously doubt you'll be able to do this in WPF. It's just not fast  enough.

Comment: Now I know that, but how to solve? Maybe a gpu rendering - or...

Comment: Concur with @HighCore, this is not the framework you are looking for. You can get a little better performance by working within the retained mode structure and overriding `OnRender` in a custom `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: @ritchmelton though you won't be able to rotate or zoom or anything else if you go that route

Comment: One thing though, I don't usually do heavy vector graphics work, but 10000 vectors for that drawing? could it be that your import process is generating way too much data?

Comment: @HighCore - You can, but you starting eating your free lunch by doing it yourself. I agree with you, wrong tool

Comment: @RitchMelton have you done any WinRT XAML? I've heard that the managed-to-native interop in MILCore is really what kills WPF performance. WinRT XAML, since it's not really managed, should not have this problem. Do you have any information about that?

Comment: Have you tried StreamGeometry ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613591.aspx

Comment: @HighCore - No, I've done stuff with the CX, but no XAML